# format text using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following text

```
1
0
0
0
0
0
ASET LANCAR


Neraca
1
1
0
0
0
0
KAS DAN SETARA KAS


Neraca
1
1
1
0
0
0
Kas
 

Buku Besar
```

using regex how can I turn that text into like:

```
100000,ASET LANCAR,Neraca
110000,KAS DAN SETARA KAS,Neraca
111000,Kas,Buku Besar
```

in other words I want to turn the original string into comma separated value (CSV). honestly I have no idea about how the regex would look like.

Comment: Can you please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55862348/2102956) and let me know if it worked for you?

Comment: yes, your answer works well..i am sorry i am having trouble with my internet connection. thank you very much.

Comment: Your're welcome and so Glad you found my solution useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need minimum two steps to achieve this.

First replace `(?<=\d)\R(?=\d)|(\s){2,}` with `\1` and you will get following text,

```
100000
ASET LANCAR
Neraca
110000
KAS DAN SETARA KAS
Neraca
111000
Kas
Buku Besar
```

Once you have this text, you can use this regex `(?<=\w)\R(?=[a-zA-Z])` and replace it with a comma `,` and you will get your desired following text,

```
100000,ASET LANCAR,Neraca
110000,KAS DAN SETARA KAS,Neraca
111000,Kas,Buku Besar
```

**Initial text,**

[image]

**After first replace,**

[image]

**After second replace you have your desirable text**

[image]